# RegisterReceiver runs always or the app must run on background?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to use a  BroadcastReceiver.
I want this receiver to run always on background, and detect when BT is enabled or disabled.
How can I create this?
I dont want an app which runs on background. I want just the receiver. Maybe I need to create a service for that?

EDIT: 
You didn't understood what I mean, I'll explain:
I want just a BroadcastReceiver, which always waits on background.
I created activity which set the BroadcastReceiver, but when I close the activity, the BroadcastReceiver closes too. I want that the BroadcastReceiver will be like service. Maybe I need to create a service which includes the BroadcastReceiver?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you refer to a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). You can use the same intent filters to launch an activity, service or even a single [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="***your intent***" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

this example is for a BroadcastReceiver. Also, can you post your code?

Here is a nice tutorial about BroadcastReceivers: [vogella articles-AndroidBroadcastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

make service as shown below

```
public class DataService extends Service {
public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.start";
Intent intent;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

for start service do this :

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataService.class));
```

For register receiver:

```
 registerReceiver(mHandleReceiver,new IntentFilter(LocationFindService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };
```

And You can check your data as you want.
for stop service

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DataService.class));
```

in Manifest file

```
<service android:name="com.trafficapp.service.DataService" > </service>

alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pintent);

        registerReceiver(mHandleReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocationFindService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
mHandleReceiver calls at every 1 second.
```

Comment: Yes I meant BroadcastReceiver, thanks.
You didn't understood what I mean, I'll explain:
I want just a BroadcastReceiver, which always waits on background.
I created activity which set the BroadcastReceiver, but when I close the activity, the BroadcastReceiver closes too. I want that the BroadcastReceiver will be like service. Maybe I need to create a service which includes the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Do your code in service.Or you can also put timertask to check your condition for some time interval.Also you can use alrma manager with broadcast receiver to check some task.